# Div sliding on top of the other div

Tags: jquery, css

I am having 2 divs element.

```
<div id='container'>
 <div class="click_menu yellow">
  <p><a href="#">Hover Me</a></p>
  <p class="subtext">The front page</p>
 </div>
 <div class="content"> <p>Content</p> </div>
</div>
```

When I hover on the first div, I would like to make slide over the top of the second one. Not pushing it down.

**[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/yy76mtmm/7/)**

How do I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: I know you might not want it, but as it is looks pretty cool tbh. Plus I wouldn't want to lose any content (unless, say, this was for a dropdown menu)

Comment: Yes, sure it is for a dropdown menu :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood your question, but see if this helps

Use the below CSS :

```
.click_menu{
    position:relative;
    z-index : 1;
}
.content {
    position:absolute;
    top: 58px;
}
```

So the relative div will go over the absolute div as the `z-index` is 1.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yy76mtmm/17/)

Answer (score 0):

You can make change in below css

```
.content {
    margin-top:50px;//added
    position:absolute;//changed
    clear: both;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background:#D52100;    
}

.click_menu{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    color:#191919;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;// added
    z-index: 100;//added
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/yy76mtmm/31/)**

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're wanting to do something really custom, there's no point in reinventing the wheel. Bootstrap does a lot of the work for you.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-dropdowns